# Radio buttons wrongly aligned in Ignored Tags block

Tags: bug, design, ignored-tags

It seems that radio buttons should be moved slightly to the top in Ignored Tags block:

> [image]

Windows 10. Google Chrome Version 109.0.5414.120 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: IMHO this is not a _bug_, it's just slightly imperfect rendering of standard HTML elements that I never would have noticed (and still have a hard time seeing why it's a problem). And I can think of about 7 billion things I'd want them to fix before they ever look at this.